# Recording Locators using Selenium in Safari Browser

Tags: firefox, testing, pdf, selenium, safari

I am testing the action of opening a PDF. In firefox I do not get a popup, but in selenium I get a save popup window. Is there a say to record this locator? or some other approach for selenium to click on that popup which only appears in Safari. I'm using Safari browser 5.0.5. Thanks!